# security+best practices: root or www-data on a wordpress content folder?

Tags: users, security, server, deployment, linux

```
    drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data
    drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data
    -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data
    -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data
    -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data
    drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data
    drwxr-xr-x  7 root     root
```

This is on a wordpress install on an AWS linux server and that "root" owned folder is where all my changes go. To write my changes to that directory I had to sudo them in, that left ownership as "root" whereas every other folder is the defacto "www-data" user group.

Is this bad? Why?

Comment: It's bad. It's well documented. If a script in there has a vulnerability then whatever your hacker wants will run as the file owner, root, allowing them to do anything.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by running this command:

```
    cd /var/www/html/
    sudo chown -Rv www-data:www-data *
```

Changed ownership back to www-data instead of root. This article helped me:

http://johnqunknown.me/fixing-wordpress-a-mini-tutorial/

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your own question, be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer after two days to indicate that this question is resolved.

Comment: Not secure - you should not give ownership to the same user running apache. https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/